# Private nameservers and DNS records

Tags: dns, nameserver

I just transferred an existing domain from one registrar to another. It has had private name servers with dnsmadeeasy.com for a long time. At the new registrar, they have the correct nameservers listed as it transferred over, but they prepopulated the DNS Records with their own info. Do I need to change the DNS info to match what I have at dnsmadeeasy or does it not matter. The only change we wanted was to move the domain from one registrar to another...all the DNS records should stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to check if you advised the domain name, but in the general case, where the nameservers registered with the registrar are not the registrars nameservers any [non NS ] domain records they might have are ignored.  Of-course, the nameservers you are pointing to need to be set up with the appropriate records.

[ I know that Crazy Domains/Dreamscape networks has a list of domain records for domains I manage which I safely ignore as I point DNS for my clients to my own nameservers - I posit many other registrars are similar ]

Comment: Hey thanks for taking the time to answer this. Private name servers are a thing,, just google that. I'm not confusing private domain registration. or anything, the question really is....If I have my nameservers at a place that is different than the registrar, does the DNS info that the registrar prepopulates...matter at all...as that info is NOT the info at the nameservers.

Comment: Private nameservers give you DNS servers under your own domain name.  They require glue records created at the registrar.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Thanks for that. That term did not exist when I was learning about them.  To me a "private nameserver" is simply a public facing authorative server (a private nameserver would be one with zones only available on a local network/intranet!)